# Powershell incorrect parameter

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to pass the file directory to the function convert at the bottom.  When I run the script I receive the output:

Succes

C:\test 2\00000027627-00001\PROCESSING CHECKLIST

convert : Invalid Parameter - 2\00000027627-00001\PROCESSING
At C:\Users\pmanca\Desktop\msbxmlreader.ps1:35 char:13
+             convert([string]$hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invalid Paramet...0001\PROCESSING:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

It appears to be cutting off the file path after C:\test.  Could the file path be too long? even so i wouldn't imagine getting the error at the function call and instead somewhere in the function when it couldn't resolve the path.

```
#? is a shortcut for where object and % is a shortcut for foreach-object
cls
#count 1 = Loan Number
#count 4 = Cust Num
#count 5 = Document Type
$hostdirectory = "C:\test 2"
$count = 0
$file = (Select-xml -Path "$hostdirectory\index.xml" -XPath / ).Node


$test = $file.ExportedResult.Docs.ExportedDoc.Doc.UdiValues.UdiValue.Value#  | Select-Object  {$_.UdiValue.Value.InnerXML} -Unique #|? {$_.UdiValue.Name -eq "Loan Number"} 


 $test | ForEach-Object{
    $count++
   # Write-Host $_.innerxml "----" $count
    if($count -eq 1){
        [string]$xmlHold = $_.InnerXML
        $hostdirectoryPlusLoan =  "$hostdirectory\$xmlHold"
        if(!(test-path $hostdirectoryPlusLoan)){
            New-Item $hostdirectoryPlusLoan -ItemType directory 
        }
    }
    if($count -eq 5){
        [string]$xmlHold = $_.InnerXML
        $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType =  "$hostdirectoryPlusLoan\$xmlHold"
        if(!(test-path $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType)){
            New-Item $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType -ItemType directory
        }
        if(Test-Path "$hostdirectory\$xmlhold.pdf"){
            $check = Copy-Item  "$hostdirectory\$xmlHold.pdf" -Destination $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if(-not $?) {write-warning "Copy Failed"; Write-Host $Error[0].exception.message}
            else {write-host "Succes"} 
            Write-Host $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType
            convert([string]$hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType)
        } 
    }

    if($count -ge 8){
        $count = 0
       # Write-Host "-----------------------------------"
    }


 }





 function convert([string]$inputDirectory){
    write-host $inputDirectory
    #Variable to hold current input directory 
    $InputPathFilter = $InputDirectory + '\*.pdf'



    #Variable to hold the list of PDFs from the current input directory
    $PDFList = @(gci $InputPathFilter | foreach {write-output $_.name})


    #Loop through list of PDF files to convert to TIF image files.
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $PDFList.count; $j++) {   
        #Each PDF will go into its own directory/batch 


        #Create a variable with only the file name
        $FileName = $PDFList[$j] -replace(".pdf",'')


        #Variable of the full path to the current PDF
        $InputPath = $InputDirectory + '\' + $PDFList[$j]


        #Variable to hold output path of each TIF file.  Filename format is that used by batches in ScerIS (i.e. 00010001.tif, 00010002.tif, etc...)
        $OutputFullDirectory = $inputlDirectory + '\' + $FileName + "_" + "{0:D4}" -f + '1' + '%04d.tif' 

        #Calls Ghostscript command line executable to process each PDF file into a group of single page TIF image files
        &'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.14\bin\gswin64c.exe' -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -r600 "-sOutputFile=$OutputFullDirectory" "$InputPath"

        #Increment the counter for the loop
        $DocCounter = $j + 1

        #Rename the current pdf so that it isn't processed again.
        $RenamePath = $PdfList[$j] -replace("pdf", "pd_")

           Rename-Item $InputPath $RenamePath -Force


    }


 }
```

Comment: Have you tried single quotes, i.e. `$hostdirectory = 'C:\test 2'`?

Comment: [This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/07/powertip-run-a-powershell-script-with-space-in-the-path.aspx) might help.

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions on the $Hostdirectory.  I still get the error.  I will most likely have spaces when i create the directory $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType.  Is there a way to cast the variables to make sure they will work with a space as well?  I still have it break between test and the 2

Comment: Have you tried calling it as `convert -inputDirectory $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType` which is the correct syntax?

Comment: this still causes the script to crash on the first space in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** : In PowerShell, when you call a function you must not use parenthesis :

```
convert $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType
```

or as suggested in comment

```
convert -inputDirectory $hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType
```

but not :

```
convert([string]$hostdirectoryPlusLoanPlusDocType)
```

**Second** : Your function should be declarated first and use after :

```
function toto ($var)
{
  Write-Host $var
}
toto "voila"
```

and not

```
toto "voila"
function toto ($var)
{
  Write-Host $var
}
```

Comment: Moving it to the top of my program solved my issue along with using the suggesting syntax for calling the function.  thanks. When i am done with the script i will update it above in case someone else comes across this,